# Hatcher chapter 0 exercise.

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

Show that $f:X \rightarrow Y$ is a homotopy equivalence if there exist maps $g,h:Y \rightarrow X$ such that $fg \simeq \mathbb{1}$ and $hf \simeq \mathbb{1}$.

Why isn't this trivial. Surely if f is a homotopy equivalence we get the maps for free with say g=h.

Comment: You are assuming you have these maps, not that you have a homotopy equivalence. The problem then is that you want to conclude that you can take $h=g$, which is not a priori obvious.

Comment: To add on Alex's comment, the implication is **IF** exists $h,g$ etc. **THEN** $f$ is homotopy equivalence. What you are asking is the other way around, you assume that $f$ is homotopy equivalence and take $g=h$; you need to prove the other direction.

Comment: @AsafKaragila It still seems really trivial.

Comment: So you have g,h and identity. Then surely, by definition f is a homotopy.

Comment: No one said that Chapter 0 exercises are difficult, most times these exercises are meant to let you play with the definition a bit and try some easy things so you can slowly wade into the material later on.

Comment: No, you are given two maps. You cannot choose them for yourself. The exercise says "I have given you these two maps. Now show me that $f$ is homotopy equivalence." and not "Give me two maps which will show this...".

Comment: @AsafKaragila I don't know. Think I'm doing it wrong. The rest of the exercises are hard.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This answer assumes the following theorem, so if it's not something you feel you can use you'll need to prove it first:

*If $f_1,g_1\colon X\to Y$ are homotopic, and $f_2,g_2\colon Y\to Z$ are homotopic, then the compositions $f_2\circ f_1$ and $g_2\circ g_1$ are also homotopic.*

Assuming this theorem, we show that if $fg\backsimeq1$ and $hf\backsimeq1$ then $g\backsimeq h$, so $1\backsimeq fg\backsimeq fh$ and $f$ is by definition a homotopy  equivalence (with inverse homotopy equivalence $h$). To do this, we use the above theorem and the associativity of composition to find:

$$h=h\circ 1\backsimeq h(fg)=(hf)g\backsimeq 1\circ g=g$$

So $g\backsimeq h$ and we have the result as above.

Comment: How do you prove the thing you are using. Hatcher asks to prove something like that earlier.

Comment: Reasonable question - does Hatcher not prove it himself? It's a fairly important theorem for a lot of the rest of the book (assuming you're talking about Algebraic Topology and not some other Hatcher book). If I recall correctly, you can prove the result I mentioned directly, by taking a homotopy $H_1$ from $f_1$ to $g_1$, and a homotopy $H_2$ from $f_2$ to $g_2$, and "composing them" to get the homotopy you want. The inverted commas are because you'll need to fiddle with $H_1$ a bit (i.e. make it map to $Y\times I$ instead of just $Y$) so that $H_2\circ H_1$ is defined.

Answer (score 5):

If you are familiar with categories then this can help:

$f:X\rightarrow Y$ is a homotopy equivalence in category $\mathbf{Top}$
is exactly the same statement as: $\left[f\right]:X\rightarrow Y$
is an isomorphism in category $\mathbf{hTop}$.

$g,h\in\mathbf{Top}\left(Y,X\right)$ with $fg\simeq1$ and $hf\simeq1$
is exactly the same statement as: $\left[g\right],\left[h\right]\in\mathbf{hTop}\left(Y,X\right)$
with $\left[f\right]\left[g\right]=1$ and $\left[h\right]\left[f\right]=1$.

Based on the last result we find: $\left[g\right]=\left[1\right]\left[g\right]=\left(\left[h\right]\left[f\right]\right)\left[g\right]=\left[h\right]\left(\left[f\right]\left[g\right]\right)=\left[h\right]\left[1\right]=\left[h\right]$.

Then we have $\left[f\right]\left[g\right]=1$ and $\left[g\right]\left[f\right]=\left[h\right]\left[f\right]=1$
or equivalently: $\left[f\right]$ is an isomorphism.

The last statement is exactly the same
statement as: $f$ is a homotopy equivalence.

Comment: Ja, dat was me al duidelijk (= that was allready clear to me).:)

Comment: @magma Thanks for edits. Oh, I am so clumsy...

Comment: You are welcome. I have't received your email yet :-)